# What Are The Uses For The Admired Ability?

Tags: fallen-london

[image: Admired] I keep seeing challenges that result in my Admired ability rising.

What use is there for this ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hugely helpful, but if you have 15 Admired you can laugh off Scandal instead of needing a friend to redirect it onto.

Edit from 2013: Admired has been renamed to Making Waves, and is now critical to making promoted professions available.

Comment: Personally I found it much easier to take exile and cash in some of the connections I wasn't using much, so I didn't have much use for Admired.

Answer (score 0):

As with all qualities in Echo Bazaar, a high admired score could in the future unlock storylets and/or opportunity cards, but [Merus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/34118/8557) is right, the only use for Admired at the moment appears to be [laughing off scandal](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Laugh_off_scandal!).